# Using numpy.isin in 2d case

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to check if elements in A is B row-wise. For example:

```py
a=np.array([[0,1],[1,2]]),b=np.array([[1,3],[1,2],[4,3],[2,3]])
```

I want to get something like`[False,True]`, since `[0,1]`in a is not in b, and `[1,2]` in a is in b. I tried `np.isin`, but it only works in element-wise.

Hope that makes sense and any help gratefully received.